# How do I assign dynamic variables with the same class?

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

I have a class called Square. I'm trying to convert strings into variables and assign each one with the same class.

```
a = 'var'
exec("%s = %d" % (a,Square()))
```

The sample code above won't work because the error says to use integer not Square:

```
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not Square
```

What does the %d have to be changed into for this to work?

Comment: Why do you need to set variables in the first place? Use a dictionary instead: `namespace = {a: Square()}` sets a key `'var'` to the instance.

Answer (score 1):

Using a dictionary works well

```
x = {}
a = 'var'
x[a]= Square()
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to put a `Square` object for an `int` placeholder.

But in your question you stated that you want to assign a dynamic variable.

Try this

```
var_name = "a"
exec("%s = Square()" % var_name)
```

You want `exec` to create the `Square` object.

Note that "dynamic variables" are probably not what you want. You are going to have the same difficulties acessing the value of the variable.

Take a look at the `dict` class. With that you can store objects represented by a key very easiely.

For example

```
# create a dictionary
my_squares = {}

# create the square and put it into the dict
my_squares["some name"] = Square()  

# do whatever you want with your square
print(my_squares["some name"])
```